# Laravel-mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

```
    $query = $this->proposal->where('status', 'approved')
                ->with(['evaluations', 'user', 'contributions'])
                ->with(['reviews' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('status','approved')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                }]);

if( .... ) {

    dd($query->toSql()); // "select * from "proposals" where "status" = ?"

    $proposalsFoundByTile = $query->where('title','like',"%$request->search%")->get();

    dd($query->toSql()); // "select  from "proposals" where "status" = ? and "title" like ?"

    ...
}
```

Why $query value changed? How can I "clear" this changes to initial value?

Comment: You applied `where` to the `$query`. It changes the query. If you need to preserve the original one for future use, create a copy.

Comment: @AlexBlex what do you mean "create a copy"? Like how?

Comment: like 

$query = ...;

$queryForSmth = $query;
$res = queryForSmth->...; 
?

Comment: Yeah, like that, but using [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) to get a copy of the object.

Comment: @AlexBlex ogromnoe thank you))))

Comment: @DenysSiebov, if u have implemented with `clone` post as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

After this line,

```
$proposalsFoundByTile = $query->where('title','like',"%$request->search%")->get();
```

put this,

```
$key = array_search("title", array_column($query->getQuery()->wheres, 
        'column'));
unset($query->getQuery()->wheres[$key]);
```

Then this will return,

```
dd($query->toSql()); // "select  from "proposals" where "status" = ?"
```

Comment: It works, but it looks like inventing a wheel. 
I will need to this this thing multiple time, it's not clear (((

Answer (score 0):

As adviced in comments solved this problem with `clone()` function.

```
$query = $this->proposal->where('status', 'approved')
                ->with(['evaluations', 'user', 'contributions'])
                ->with(['reviews' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('status','approved')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                }]);

if( .... ) {

    $subQuery = clone($query);
    $proposalsFoundByTile = $subQuery->where('title','like',"%$request->search%")->get();

    ...

   $subQuery = clone($query);
   $some_var = $subQuery->... ; 
}
```